# How to prove this $n$-var inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction

> If non negative real numbers $a_1$, $a_2$$\dots$, $a_n$ satisfy $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i=1$, prove that\[\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}a_ia_j\left(a_i^2+a_j^2\right)\le\frac18.\]

I think we can use induction because $\left(\frac12,\frac12,0,\dots,0\right)$ and its permutations are (possibly not the only?) equality cases. So we start with $3$-var.

We need to prove $8\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}\left(a_1^3a_2+a_1a_2^3\right)\le\left(\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a_1\right)^3$, or
\[8\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a_1^2a_2a_3+\left(\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a_1^2-2\sum\limits_{\rm cyc}a_1a_2\right)^2\ge0~,\]
(by the undetermined coeffitients), which is true.

For the induction step, assume $n-1$-var version is proven, we need to consider the $n$-var version. I tried to apply the inductive assumption on the $n$ numbers
\[a_1,a_2\dots,a_{n-2},a_{n-1}+a_n,\]but it failed.

Comment: A minor point, but you probably need $n > 1$ for this to be true

Comment: @Gregory For $n=1$, the $\sum_{1\leq i < j\leq n}$ is an empty sum and thus $0$. The result holds.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7B1%5Cle%20i%5Clt%20j%5Cle%20n%7Da_ia_j(a_i%5E2%2Ba_j%5E2)%5Cle%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B8%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7Da_i%3D1%24&p=1), there's [If $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1$ and $x_{i}\ge 0$ then $\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}x_{i}x_{j}(x_{i}+x_{j})\le\frac{1}{4}$](/q/2143554), where the RHS is the considerably weaker limit of $\frac{1}{4}$ instead. Also, there's several related AoPS threads, e.g., ...

Comment: (cont.) [IMO ShortList 1999, algebra problem 1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h19778p131846), [Strange Inequalities](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1602694p9981420), etc.